# How do I create a has_and_belongs_to_many association with one main record

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

Let's say I have the models Developers and Projects, and developers has_and_belongs_to_many projects and projects has_and_belongs_to_many developers. What is the best way to set up the associations where one of the developer's projects should be his main project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with:

Developer

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
has_one :main_project, :class_name => "Project"
```

Assuming the classes are Developer and Project.